# Navigate to another page from ListTile

Tags: flutter

My app got a expandable List with multiple entries. I want to navigate to different pages by clicking on the ListTiles on the lowest level. I know that there's the 'onTap' method but it requires a buildContext which I dont have the way I programmed it. 
I got the code from the web and modified it just a little. Heres the Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../screens/model_view_screen.dart';
import '../models/entry.dart';

class EntryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const EntryItem(this.entry);
  final Entry entry;

  Widget _buildTiles(Entry root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            border: Border.all(
              width: 2,
              color: Color.fromRGBO(3, 120, 163, 1),
            ),
          ),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Image.asset(root.imageUrl),
            title: Text(root.title),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          border: Border.all(
            width: 3,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(3, 120, 163, 1),
          ),
        ),
        child: ExpansionTile(
          key: PageStorageKey<Entry>(root),
          leading: Image.asset(root.imageUrl),
          title: Text(root.title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          children: root.children.map<Widget>(_buildTiles).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(entry);
  }
}
```

The routeName of the destination is given in a List:

```
class Entry{
  final String title;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String routeName;
  final List<Entry> children;

  Entry(this.title, this.imageUrl, this.routeName, [this.children = const <Entry>[]]);
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass `BuildContext` to `_buildTiles`:

```dart
  Widget _buildTiles(BuildContext context, Entry root) {
  ....
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Image.asset(root.imageUrl),
            title: Text(root.title),
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(root.routeName),
          ),
  ....
          children: root.children.map((e) => _buildTiles(context, e)).toList(),
  ....

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(context, entry);
  }
```

Comment: I already tried that solution but when i do this i get following error: 'The argument type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Entry)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(Entry)'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)'  the eroor is marked at '_buildTiles' in this line: children: root.children.map<Widget>(_buildTiles).toList(),